# Connecting a Device to Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, device

Previously I have been using Windows 8.1 and Android Studio to develop Android apps and all was well.  However I have now just upgraded to Windows 10 and I am having a Slight Issue.

I have a Nexus 7 that I am using to debug, and Android Studio can no longer see this device to use it.  As I said all was well in Windows 8.1.

Has anyone else come across this, and have you managed to get round it?  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks again

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got exactly the same issue. Steps to fix that.

```
#1 Uninstall driver
#2 Unplug device and restart pc
#3 Plug device and install driver downloaded from the web not from device
```

Comment: Thank you sir - worked a treat.  Im in danger of actually getting some work done today now.

Answer (score 1):

A day looking for a solution of the same problem like you.
I use a Sony C4 and Android Studio on Windows 10, 
my problem of my phone is not detected in Windows 10.

You can check in MyComputer> Properties> Device Manager.

**The first step**

1. I downloaded [OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers) for my phone, see the list of OEM Drivers url
2. create a directory "usb_driver" in <.sdk.>\extras\google\

> <.sdk.> = C:\Users\Karebet\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\

3. I extract OEM USB Drivers then copy paste to <.sdk.>\extras\google\usb_driver\

**The second step**

1. I not download from the SDK but from [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
2. I extract the Google USB Drivers then copy paste to <.sdk.>\extras\google\usb_driver\

not include directory "amd64" and "i386"

**Third step**

1. Right-click MyComputer> Properties> Device Manager
2. check whether there is a device not in the know in Others Device

if there: right-click> Properties> Tab "Driver"> Update Driver> Browser my computer blabla > select dir usb_driver in <.sdk.>\extras\google\, 
and click OK . wait a while Driver has been detected

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install a Google USB driver (sdk\extras\google\usb_driver) using Device Manager, but it said "Windows was unable to install your USB Composite Device".

I use this universal ADB driver pack (from Koush.com)
https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver